# How to show decimal to a double property with whole number value

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, double, radgridview

Having issues when I assign a whole value like so

```
double myDouble = 1.0;
```

...to a variable. When I display this on a textblock in telerik it would show "1" instead of "1.0".

Other values with decimal places are working as expected.

**EDIT**
I'm using wpf with telerik Datagrid. But before I place the value to the Datagrid I convert it to a string. So before that happens I assign the value like so.

This is my class:

```
public class MyClass{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public double MyDoubleVal {get;set;}
}
```

This is how I assign the value

```
var class = new MyClass { Id = 1, MyDoubleVal = 1.0 };
```

When I debug and tried to check the value, it shows as "1" and not "1.0". Now when I place the value to show on the DataGrid I can manually add the decimal place but I'd rather not do that if there's a formatting function that can take care of that for me.

So far I've tried the following

```
String.Format(""{0:00.0}", myClassInstance.MyDouble);
myClassInstance.MyDouble.ToString("0.0")
```

Comment: How do you "show" the value.  You are in total control of how many digits via the format.  Which platform might also be informative

Comment: Are you using Telerik WPF control or Ajax control?

Comment: updated. @JerryLiang , using wpf

Comment: Does Telerik's DataGrid not have a format option? Edit: [It looks like it does](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/data-formatting).

Comment: the telerik control in wpf is actually known as a `gridview` not `datagrid`.  might pay to correct your post

Comment: The debug will always print 1.0 or even 1.00000 with 1. In my past experience, I had to format number value in binding using StringFormat method all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format `F`:

```
double a = 1.0;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("F"));
```

Will [output](https://ideone.com/qqMdwp) `1.00`

Comment: So I have a class that has a double property. I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. When I debug it and check the current value, it shows "1" on the property and not 1.0. I assigned the value as 1.0 on the contructor. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @gdubs value of property and it's string presentation may differ. Using `a.ToString("F")` you force to show value with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. Some of them are as follow:

**string.Format():**

```
double a = 18.54657;//some number
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F2}", a);
// where F2 tells the function to format as a float with 2 decimals... for your usecase you can use F1
```

**double.ToString():**

```
double a = 18.54657;//some number
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("#.#");
//where the # after the period tells the function to include 1 number after the period(or 1 decimal point). You can add more # for more decimal points to show. As a side not you can do a.ToString("#,###.#") to add commas to numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your double value in XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDoubleVal, StringFormat=n1}" />
```

if there is only Content property then use ContentStringFormat instead